# Generic getter with C++11

Tags: c++11, generics, decltype

I want to try to do a generic getter by using C++11, but I have an issue if I try to define the generic getter outside the template class.

This code works fine

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
  public:
    ........
    //generic getter
    template <typename F>
    auto getter_elem_member(F fun)->decltype(fun())
    { return elem.fun(); }
  private
    T elem;                             
};
```

but if I try the code in this way:

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
  public:
    ........
    //generic getter
    template <typename F>
    auto getter_elem_member(F fun)->decltype(fun());
  private
    T elem;                             
};

template <typename T>
template <typename F>
auto test<T>::getter_elem_member(F fun)->decltype(fun())
{ return elem.fun(); }
```

I obtain the error "Member declaration not found".
Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

I am doing exercises with new features, here a example that works (unless a warning)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class test
{
    public:
    //costruttori - distruttori
    test(){}
    ~test(){}

    public:
    //generic getter
    template <typename F>
    auto getter_elem_member(F fun)
    { return (elem.*fun)(); }

    //generic getter
    template <typename F>
    auto getter_elem_member2(F fun)->decltype(fun())
    { return fun(); }


    private:
    T elem;                             
};

struct A
{
  std::string print(){return "ciao";}
    static   std::string print2(){return "ciao";}
};

int main()
{
test<A> test1;
std::cout << test1.getter_elem_member(&A::print) << std::endl;

std::cout << test1.getter_elem_member2(A::print2) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: What type is F? I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Add a complete example so we can try it for ourselves. This code is incomplete and (with some minor typo fixes), [appears to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d9b122583cbf0b0).

Comment: I am doing exercises with new features. Here a complete example working (unless a warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make a proxy function which calls a member function of a private member variable through a member function pointer, I don't think you need `decltype` at all.

```
// Member function pointer version
template <class Ret>
Ret getter_elem_member(Ret (T::*fun)())
{ return (elem.*fun)(); }

// Generic function object version
template <class F>
auto getter_elem_member(F fun) -> decltype(fun())
{ return fun(); }
```

If a function pointer is given, the first one will be called. For other callable types, the second one will be called.

The second one, which is for a generic callable object, seems unnecessary. Since you can't access the private member in `fun` anyway, so it's better calling `fun()` outside than passing it and making your class call it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to use a template function-like paradigm.
You should use std::function to do this. If not, you can probably get along with some sort of templated function pointer to do this.